# as3 Android access csv file in download folder

Tags: android, file, actionscript-3, location

For my app I want to send the user a text file of data on an e-mail which they save in the download folder on their Android device.

The app will then pull the data from that file and use it in the app. In the desktop version URLLoader works fine with the file copied into the app source directory, but that method does not work on an Android device.

Storage permission is set.

I have tried using the Filestream method and manually copying the file into the app directory on the device, but that does not seem to work.

Ideally I want to be able to set path for the file to the device's download folder so that the user experience is as simple as it can be.

And before you ask, usage will be on wifi only tablets with questionable wifi access - sending e-mails with the file upfront is the only reliable way to handle this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Adam

Comment: I suggest you google how to save text files with okio library.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!   Please update your question and show the relevant code that you've tried in regards to Filestream.  This will help someone with a starting point on how to answer your question.     Also please describe in more detail what *'doesn't seem to work'* means - is there an error? if so share it.

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is not the code to read the file, it is putting the file in a place which is easily accessible for the user (the downloads folder) which can then be read by the app. In short, is it possible to set the path for Filestream to the device download folder? Having spent 2 days looking, I have come up with nothing on this.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile devices the File.applicationDirectory , is a read  only folder, try to use File.application**Storage**Directory

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html